# Check box class based click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to find out which check box is selected in a group of check boxes and read its value.

The following is the checkbox format

```
<div class="panel-body smoothscroll maxheight300 brand_select">
    <div class="block-element">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="0"  />
            Armani </label>
    </div>
    <div class="block-element">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="1" />
            Gucci </label>
    </div>
    <div class="block-element">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="2" />
            Louis Vuitton </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried giving class names but it didn't work. I gave class names as `class="brand_name"` and tried to read through jquery click function

```
$('.brand_name').click(function () {
    console.log("click worked")
});
```

But it didn't work. Can someone suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: your code shud work if you are properly adding the class to the `input`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/docLj6k3/).

Answer (score 3):

You are applying the `click` event handler on `div` and not on `checkboxes`

```
$('.brand_select').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

To get list of all checked values:

```
$('.brand_select').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {

    var checkedEl = [];
    $('.brand_name :checkbox').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkedEl.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    console.log('Checked values');
    console.log(checkedEl);
});
```

Comment: I don't see the class `brand_name` on any of his div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function () {
    if(this.checked){
        alert($(this).val());
    }else{
       // ......... 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class to input elements and change the name of the fields so that you can use them as array -

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="term[]" value="2" class="brand_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
$('input[name="term"]').on('change', function(){
  alert($(this).val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body smoothscroll maxheight300 brand_select">
          <div class="block-element">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="0"  />
              Armani </label>
          </div>
          <div class="block-element">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="1" />
              Gucci </label>
          </div>
          <div class="block-element">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"  name="term" value="2" />
              Louis Vuitton </label>
          </div>
</div>
```